# Why is this code no solution to the critical section problem?

Tags: process, synchronization, mutex, critical-section

I'm trying to understand process synchronisation and have been thinking the past couple of hours about this piece of code and why it is not a suitable solution to the critical section problem. My take on this problem would be that Progress is not fullfilled since turn can be only modified inside of the first inner while loop but I am not quite sure about that. 
I would be really thankful for any thougts and tips regarding this matter.

```
// initialised with FALSE. 
    boolean flag [2];
// With values 0, 1. Any initialisation.
int turn;

while TRUE {
    flag [i] = TRUE ;

    while ( turn != i) {
        while ( flag [j]) {
            noop ;
         }
         turn =i;

    }
criticalSection (Pi);
flag [i] = FALSE ;
remainderSection (Pi);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to invent your own locking algorithm (e.g., something along the lines of [Lamport's bakery algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm). But your example looks like it's missing things (e.g., shouldn't your loop _increment_ the `turn` variable?) Also it might be helpful if you could highlight what is a _local_ variable (maybe `turn`?) and what is a shared variable (e.g., the `flag` array.)

Comment: Also, be aware that you will need to use [memory barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) in order to implement your own locking algorithm on any modern, multi-processor computer system.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. turn and flag are  supoosed to be global variables.

Comment: Furthermore this is supposed to be pseudo code that was given as an example on how not to solve a CS problem. But there was no explanation to it